# How to collect data from a stream in a closure without memory leaks/lifecycle?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a class which takes a stream as argument with an initial value and just execute logic everytime a value is emitted. I thought I could do this with `MutableStateFlow`, but that only will transmit after I called `launchIn` with a coroutine scope. The code is executed without coroutines and no lifecycle, so this is a no-go. Executing it with a `GlobalScope` scope will leak memory. The class needs to be deinitialized when there are no references to it anymore.

Essentially I am just looking for a [CurrentValueSubject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject) equivalent. I am looking for something like this:

```
fun listen(stream: StreamWithInitialValue<Boolean>) { 
    now = stream.currentValue

    someStrongReference = stream.sink { newBoolean -> 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Preferabele without any third party libraries.

Comment: Launching a flow collection in GlobalScope only leaks memory if you fail to cancel the returned Job when you're done collecting. Any other class you build to do this will have the same basic necessity--you will have to remove or cancel your subscription when you're done so your subscription lambda doesn't leak all the references that it captures. One possible workaround is to store subscription lambdas in the stream class using WeakReferences, but then you put the responsibility on the subscriber that it must hold a strong reference to its listener for as long as it wants updates to continue.